# Get Facebook's friend gender

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an Android app that connects with Facebook to get user facebook's friends.

To do it, I use this URL `"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="` but it doesn't return friends's gender.

**How can I do it to get friends's gender?**

Maybe I have to add some parameter to the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Displaying a `Friend` object only displays his `ID` and `name`.

You have to indicate that you want the gender!

```
me/friends?fields=gender&access_token=
```

If you still want the name:

```
me/friends?fields=gender,name&access_token=
```

Comment: A small warning: This works now, but may not work with Facebook API V. 2.